# How can I add in a where clause to a select in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following:

```
var result =
    from entry in feed.Descendants(a + "entry")
    let content = entry.Element(a + "content")
    let properties = content.Element(m + "properties")
    let text = properties.Element(d + "Text")
    let title = properties.Element(d + "Title")
    let partitionKey = properties.Element(d + "PartitionKey")
    select new Content
    {
        Text = text.Value,
        Title = title.Value
    };
```

What I would like to do is to add a where so that only some items are placed into result. How can I add in the condition:

```
partitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "03" && text != null
```

to the select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the condition before the select:

```
var result =
    from entry in feed.Descendants(a + "entry")
    let content = entry.Element(a + "content")
    let properties = content.Element(m + "properties")
    let text = properties.Element(d + "Text")
    let title = properties.Element(d + "Title")
    let partitionKey = properties.Element(d + "PartitionKey")
    where partitionKey.Value.Substring(2, 2) == "03"
    where text != null
    select new Content
    {
        Text = text.Value,
        Title = title.Value
    };
```

Comment: It says XElement does not contain a definition for Substring

Comment: I just followed your exact where condition... I adjusted my code to handle XElement.

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
where partitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "03" && text != null
```

use

```
where partitionKey.Value.Substring(2, 2) == "03" && text != null
```

partitionKey is of type XElement, when you need it's value.

Answer (score 1):

Specify `where` before the `select`:

```
var result =
    from entry in feed.Descendants(a + "entry")
    let content = entry.Element(a + "content")
    let properties = content.Element(m + "properties")
    let text = properties.Element(d + "Text")
    let title = properties.Element(d + "Title")
    let partitionKey = properties.Element(d + "PartitionKey")
    where partitionKey.Substring(2, 2) == "03" && text != null
    select new Content
    {
        Text = text.Value,
        Title = title.Value
    };
```

Comment: It says XElement does not contain a definition for Substring

Answer (score 1):

```
        var result =
from entry in feed.Descendants(a + "entry")
let content = entry.Element(a + "content")
let properties = content.Element(m + "properties")
let text = properties.Element(d + "Text")
let title = properties.Element(d + "Title")
let partitionKey = properties.Element(d + "PartitionKey")
where partitionKey.Value.Substring(2, 2) == "03" && text != null
select new Content
{
    Text = text.Value,
    Title = title.Value
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a  linquer software which converts SQL scripts into LINQ ,imagine this at a time of Inner Joins and more complecx query ?

visit : [www.sqltolinq.com/](http://www.sqltolinq.com/%E2%80%8E)‎

It is very handy tool!!